# How can I display my maps (from maps.google.com) on Android smartphone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-maps

How can I access to "my maps" saved from desktop website (maps.google.com) from my mobile device?

When I use maps application on my device I am not able to find my saved maps with my POI and my settings

I am using Android 4.4 on Nexus 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google finally offers the solutions:

[Google Maps Engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b) can solve the problem and is free available in the Play Store

[image]

Comment: However the integration has been lost.

Comment: I have to check but it seems that it has only changed the name

Comment: Yes the name has recently changed but I meant something different: the integration in a single Maps application has been lost.

Answer (score 3):

Have you explored the layers option in your Maps app? Your saved maps can be shown as a layer.

In the following image (courtsey: HowTo.Cnet.com) you can see the "My maps" section. Expanding My Maps will show all your saved maps. It requires a data connection to use this feature.
[image]

Update:
While composing this reply, I cross checked my input with the Google Maps app in my mobile. My mobile is running v2.3.3 and having Google Maps of version 6.x. I could see the "My maps" section in the layer and I could overlay one of my saved maps.

When I saw OP's comment that "My maps" was not found, I cross checked it with my Nexus 7 running 4.3.3 and Google Maps v7.3.3. It has indeed no "My maps" at all. After some search, I understood from [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/maps/W_N9mleCUmo) page that "My Maps" has been removed - may be in favour of [Google Maps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html). [image]

Update:
I just found a new app from Google at its Play store named "Google maps engine" which seems to overlay the stored (though not the old ones, but only the ones that were created with new Google maps for desktop) maps.

Comment: When I start maps I can only have to dark image you have posted here, I am not able to find Layers as in your left image (I use maps v 7.2.0)

Comment: What version are you using to have those capture screen?

Comment: I didn't capture the screen, as I said I took it from how.to.cnet.com. my phone has maps of version 6.x and there was no further update. Once went home, I noticed my nexus 7having maps 7.3 doesn't have my maps. However, I was able to see my previous searches and places, but no saved maps. After searching in internet, I saw this [page](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/maps/W_N9mleCUmo), which says this feature is removed.

Comment: This feature was removed :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at the millions of complaints on Google forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/maps/my$20maps$20android$20app$20

(It's actually a pity there are so many of them, if people searched before posting there would be fewer and stronger threads)

Looks like version 7 removed not just one useful feature:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/kRm9Tfvmp2k%5B1-25-false%5D

Answer (score 1):

Google finally integrated My Maps with the regular Android Google Maps app. Click on the menu in Google Maps app, then Your Places, and you will see your My Maps listed near the bottom after Saved Places.

Comment: Not available in iOS Google Maps as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Maps Version 9.7.1 from the Play Store today, and am now able to view My Maps within the regular Maps app.

Note that I had to actively install the newest version of Maps via the Play Store, it did not update automatically.