# How can I access bookmarked 'my places' maps from android phone?

Tags: google-maps

I have a map that was created on a desktop (map with a set of pins pointing to specific types of shops in a town - [this one](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/ms?msid=201928560945354448703.00045e51ad6f1abc1c6b5&msa=0)). I am able to save this to My Places and it shows as being bookmarked when I'm using the full desktop browser. However, when I open up the google maps app on my HTC One I can't see how to access any saved maps or bookmarks.

All I can see in my map profile (selecting the person avatar next to the search field) is my browsing history, but not my saved map. There is a 'saved places' section in my map profile page, but there's nothing in there and it's not a selectable item as far as I can tell.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

How can I save maps via the 'desktop' browsers so I can access them on my phone at a later date?

Comment: I don't think you can access "custom maps" that you have created with the Googles Maps Engine via the Google Maps Android app (I assume that is what you are referring to)? The "Saved Places" (of which you don't appear to have any?) would appear to be _singular_ places that have been saved within the App or on the Desktop. "Saved Places" is usually presented as a list of clickable places (if you have any). Once you have some _saved places_ you then get a second list of "Nearby saved places".

Comment: @w3d: I've added a link to the map that I'm referring to into the question. If I access that via desktop I can 'Save to My Places' and it gets bookmarked. However I cannot retrieve it from google maps app on my phone. You might be right that I can't retrieve custom maps, that could well be the answer to this question - i.e. "you can't". But hopefully that's not the case.

Comment: it seems a duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55541/how-can-i-display-my-maps-from-maps-google-com-on-android/70293#70293

Answer (score 3):

Since the update to Google Maps last year you should now use [Google Maps Engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) to create custom maps and access these on Android via the corresponding [Maps Engine app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b).

From Desktop Maps you can get to Maps Engine by clicking in the search box and then clicking 'My Custom Maps'.

To import existing maps saved to 'Classic' My Maps:

1. go to 'My Custom Maps'
2. then 'See all my custom maps'
3. in the 'Open a map' window, select 'Classic My Maps'
4. tick the maps you want to import and then 'Select'
5. followed by 'Import'

You should then be able to find these maps in the Android Maps Engine app under 'Open a map' > 'Classic maps'.

If your map wasn't created by you (will show as 'bookmarked' rather than 'created by you' in [My Places](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/mm)) then you might need to re-import it into 'My Places' as KML to make it available to import into Maps Engine...

1. Click the name of the map in 'My Places' (found by clicking the little cog icon in the bottom right of 'new' Maps or at https://www.google.co.uk/maps/mm)
2. In the left hand panel copy the link to the KML file
3. Back at 'My Places', click 'Create with classic My Maps'
4. Give the map a title then 'Import'
5. Paste in the URL of the KML link and 'Upload from URL'

You should now be able to go back to Maps Engine and import the map as above.

Answer (score 1):

Google finally integrated My Maps with the regular Android Google Maps app. Click on the menu in Google Maps app, then Your Places, and you will see your My Maps listed near the bottom after Saved Places.